# Build a list for all the file name of a directory

Tags: python

This posting shows how to add all files in a directory to an list in python

[How to list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)

```
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(src_dir) if isfile(join(src_dir,f)) ]
```

How can I remove the file extension in the onlyfiles list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to split a filename string into the filename and the extension.

```
from os.path import join, splitext    

onlyfiles = [splitext(f)[0] for f in listdir(src_dir) if isfile(join(src_dir,f)) ]
```

Note that `splitext` will effectively split at the "final" extension. So if you had a filename "filename.pdf.txt" it will split it into ("filename.pdf", "txt").